# Log-in redirect in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, extensions

i am using Joomla 2.5 inbuilt registration Form .i need to redirect to 2 different pages after different type of user log-in .Can this possible ? .Now my log-in menu redirecting every user to one constant page After successful log-in .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

Create a [User Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) for handling user types and redirect accoording to your requirement.
you can use `onUserAfterLogin`. Details can be found [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAfterLogin).

for redirecting just use.

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect('url starts with index.php');
```

Hope its helps..

Comment: i am using "Redirect on Login" components to re re-direct .Do you have any idea about this components?

Comment: No but once you wrote a plugin for this based on `onUserAfterLogin` then immediately redirect to your required pages will work fine for your requirement.

Comment: you're welcome :)

Comment: hey do you now how to change user group ?

Comment: from backend ? go to users menu.

Comment: no by Php Code.

Answer (score 1):

Several extensions are available at [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/login-redirect) will allow you to do this. Both free and paid alternatives can be found.

You can redirect the users based on user group or access level, or on a per-user basis. There are also some plugins that handle failed login attempts.